# Find Failed row/rows on SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer exception and retrySqlBulkCopy by omitting those rows that failed

Tags: c#, sql-server, bulkinsert, sqlbulkcopy, sqlclient

I am trying to do a bulk insert of a List of object (List invoices). Sometimes it fails and throws an exception. However, I want to know which rows failed. This way I can redo the bulk insert by omitting those rows. Can I do this?

Comment: Did you check the log files in the SQL Server (LDF)?

Comment: The exception will NOT give details about all erroneous records in that batch. It just indicates if there's a PRIMARY KEY constraint or FOREIGN KEY constraint violation. You may run a query before bulk insert to check incoming data quality

Comment: I'm not sure how more focused you can be, if you post an example of the code you are using, a sample dataset and one of the exceptions and the SQL response when you try and Insert that row manually, then this would be a complete question

Comment: If the table has any self-relationships, FKs pointing to the same table, then this could be something as simple as the order of the data being copied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the draw backs to using *Bulk* operations, the feedback is an all or none kind of response.

> When we use *Bulk* operations we are generally bypassing the validation and verification that would normally take place for each individual row, that is the main trade-off to improve performance. You can't have both.

### `SqlBulkCopy` is deliberately designed for use with sanitised data

So you should first consider how to sanitise your data before you try to copy it, this can take many forms so we can't cover everything in this post.

The most common Constraints that can fail is with null values (in fields that do not support nulls) and foreign keys (either null or not matching).
Usually we can pre-validate the bulk data for nulls and keys that do not yet exist, just query your bulk set to find the rows that have null values in columns that do not support nulls. You can also query for any rows where the values in foreign key columns do not yet exist in the target data base.

> You have not provided any detail on the structure of your data that you have in memory, so this is an abstract example for filtering based on nulls:
>
> ```
> DataTable bulkData;
> ... load the data
> // Columns that do not support nulls: Col1, Col3
> DataRow[] dataWithNulls = bulkData.Select("[Col1] IS NULL OR [Col3] IS NULL");
> // Get only rows that do not have nulls
> DataRow[] bulkDataSanitised = bulkData.Select("[Col1] IS NOT NULL AND [Col3] IS NOT NULL");
> ```
>
> To do a similar query on missing FKs you must first get a distinct list of the FK values, then query the DB to find those values that do not have a match, then you can filter out the rows that have those missing FK values.

If you are approaching this from a generic point of view, so you do not know the table schema in advance then the conceptual process that we usually follow in this scenario is to break the bulk set down into smaller chunks and execute those chunks.

In your interface, allow the user to specify the start row and the number of rows to copy, if it works, remove the rows from the source set. If it fails, ask the user to try again.

---

Your last option is to not do this in bulk at all! You can still use `SqlBulkCopy` however only send one row at a time, this allows you to handle wach row when it fails.

If you were using `SqlBulkCopy` for performance reasons, *(there are of course other non-performance reasons to use SqlBulkCopy)* then all that performance is lost if you use this method, however if failure has a low frequency then first trying the full bulk operation, then on failure doing it row by row is an option.

This article on Code Project [Retrieving failed records after an SqlBulkCopy exception](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/387465/retrieving-failed-records-after-an-sqlbulkcopy-exc) explains a solution to assist this but it should be pretty easy for you to come up with your own implementation.

---

You could combine the two approaches, trying the whole lot first, then on failure splitting the table into a number of sub tables on failure, then continue to recursively try and then split the tables until you reach tables of 1 row. This would be similar to how the user could go through the same process of elimiation manually and would still retain some performance benefits over going row by row from the start, but this is only advisable for large sets that have relatively low failure rates.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I also noticed that there is : BulkCopy.SqlRowsCopied event and blkcopy.NotifyAfter. Does using the callback slow things down that its not worth using?

Comment: `NotifyAfter` is used for logging successful progress but the failure issues are still the same, you get progress until the copy process fails, when it fails you still won't know which row caused the failure, even when setting `NotifyAfter` to 1, there is still a level of indeterminancy

Comment: You could set the `BatchSize` to 1 and the `NotifyAfter` to 1 then you would have an accurate record of the last successful row, but really once we've done that, what was the point of using `BulkCopy` in the first place.

Comment: Hi Chris, FYI, I tried to use recursion, but feel its not a good option to divide and conquer writes as the call stack balloons....may work for smaller BulkInserts. Appreciate all the advice.

Comment: Ultimately it sounds like SqlBulkCopy is not the right way to go here at all. Do what you can to pre-validate the data if you must use it, or allow the user to specify start-end row then they can deal with the errors. If this is _NOT_ a data import scenario... then you should have a lot more control and be able to sanitise the data before processing. If you have trouble identifying the actual errors, post a new question so we can help you with that.